# Interruption triggered twice when set to FALLING

Tags: interrupt, debounce

I have a simple sketch with a button that triggers an interruption set to happen when the button pin goes from HIGH to LOW. It has debouncing so no repetitions happen when the button is pressed, but sometimes when releasing the button the interruption also fires. Why would that be? Shouldn't the debouncing take care of any micro-rising during the release of the button?

```
volatile int contador = 0;
int n = contador;

long t = 0;
void setup() {    

    pinMode(2, INPUT_PULLUP);
    attachInterrupt( 0, incrementaContador, FALLING);
} 

void loop() {   
    if (n != contador) {
        n = contador;
    }
}

void incrementaContador() {

    if ( millis() > (t + 50) ) {
        contador++ ;
        t = millis();
    }
}
```

This same code works correctly when set to LOW instead of FALLING.

Comment: `Shouldn't the debouncing take care of any micro-rising during the release of the button?` - That depends on the debouncing. Schematic please?

Comment: Also if you think that "if" in your ISR is good debouncing you're sorely mistaken.

Comment: Think about what happens. You press the button, and the ISR triggers on each bounce. It counts once because all the bouncing happens within 50ms. Then, say 100ms later, you release the button. Again bouncing happens, and the ISR triggers on each bounce, and one of them within a 50ms window gets counted. You have no distinction between rising bounce and falling bounce. It's all up-down-up-down-up. The real thing you should be looking for is the *final position that hasn't changed for a while*.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Majenko. The schematic is just a button attached to pin 2 and ground. I forgot to mention that this code works perfectly when the interruption is set to trigger on LOW instead of FALLING. I checked to see if incrementing the delay in the ISR would help and with 500ms it debounces also the releasing of the button. But why the difference between the two modes. Does FALLING also trigger when 0v is not reached?

Comment: This question seems to have been abandoned.

Answer (score 2):

> but sometimes when releasing the button the interruption also fires

Yes, well when you release the button it may also bounce. In other words OFF/ON/OFF so that will count as a press. A capacitor over the switch might be better.

Example:

[image: Hardware debounce]